# How to get host name in http response in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httpresponse

I am using http module of node.js for making a request. I have bunch of urls in database. I am fetching these urls from database and making requests in loop. But when response comes, I want to get host name of that response, because I want to update something in database based on that response. But I am not getting for which site I am getting response, so I am unable to update record for that site.

Code is something like this:

```
for (site = 0; site < no_of_sites; site++) {
    options = {
        hostname: sites[site].name,
        port: 80,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0'
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {

            //Update record;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get host site in `this` object.

```
console.log(this._header.match(/Host\:(.*)/g));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option one**: use `res.req`

```
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  console.log(res.req._headers.host)
});
```

**Option two**: use a closure

```
for (site = 0; site < no_of_sites; site++) {
    (function(){
        var options = {
            // ...
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
            // options available here
            console.log(options);
        });
    }());
}
```

**Option three**:

It seems `this` is the same as `res.req` in the `http.request()` callback, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: thanks for answering, though your answer doesn't worked, it lead me to answer after some experimenting.

Comment: @sushant Really? What worked for you then? I'd like to improve my answer if it is not correct

Answer (score 1):

The answer is
console.log(res.socket._httpMessage._headers.host);